# Compiler says function is never called, but it is called

Tags: function, rust

I have a function called `record` that takes a buffer to read a file and a struct. I call it in `main` but Cargo tells me that it is never called.

```
warning: unused `std::result::Result` that must be used
   --> src/main.rs:246:5
    |
246 |     record(buffer,&mut multithreading_robots);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
    = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
```

[Complete code](https://framagit.org/azetoy/DancingDroids/-/blob/5f4be4951f29c4412fa005c775623abd65476a67/src/main.rs)

The contents of my file

```
5 5

5 5 S
F

1 0 N
R
```

thanks to your comments I hope it will be more readable now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler tells you something and you don't understand, posting what the compiler tells you is a better idea than posting your misunderstanding:

```
warning: unused `std::result::Result` that must be used
   --> src/main.rs:246:5
    |
246 |     record(buffer,&mut multithreading_robots);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
    = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
```

Cargo is not telling you that `record` is unused, it's telling you that the *result* of `record` is unused: `Result` has [the attribute `must_use`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#the-must_use-attribute), this means that a warning will be generated when a value of type `Result` is implicitly ignored (which is the case here), because it provides a useful signal which should at most be *explicitly suppressed* rather than completely ignored.

Here there are multiple ways in which `record` could fail if the input data fails to parse, but by ignoring the result you will not know whether `record` has failed, let alone how.

The easiest solution is to tack on an `?` at the end of the call, this way if `record` fails the error will be bubbled up to the top of `main`, at which point an error message wil be printed and the program will signal failure (with an exit code of 1, I don't know that that's overridable sadly).